# Azure Function v2 references a project with a higher version of Newtonsoft.Json than Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am writing a v2 Azure Durable Function. When passing a C# object to a helper activity Function, I get a runtime error in my custom `JsonConverter`used in serializing the type being passed. The custom `JsonConverter` is in a library that must reference Newtonsoft.Json 12.x, while Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions is locked into 11.0.2.

> jObject  error CS1705: Assembly 'ContractLibrary' with identity 'ContractLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' with identity 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

I believe this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4049) is relevant. [This comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4049#issuecomment-470706577) on that Issue seems to indicate that adding Newtonsoft.Json 12.x as a direct dependency of your Function project may help. This helped in another Function project, but now I have hit this wall again. Is there anything I can do to mitigate this?

Comment: Exactly what is in 12 that you need...as from one of the comments on GitHub mentioned to downgrade your version needs.... ?

Comment: Doing as you say (direct reference in the functions project) has worked for me every time. You might also need to disable just the specific warning it generates (NU1608) in your project config if you have Warnings As Errors on.

Comment: What is the wall you ran into?

Comment: @ChrisGillum The wall I ran into is the runtime error quoted.

Comment: you need to use what @ChrisGillum suggested below. it's a great answer and upvote it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is to bypass the serialization logic used by Durable Functions and do your own serialization. For example, instead of doing this:

```cs
public static void MyFunc([ActivityTrigger] MyCustomType input)
{
    // ...
}
```

Try doing this:

```cs
public static void MyFunc([ActivityTrigger] JObject json)
{
    // manually convert the JObect into MyCustomType
}
```

Let me know if that gets you any further.